# Typescript property does not exist on type when using a type where property should exist

Tags: typescript, type-safety

I am using a function which takes a message handler function as an argument. The message handler is defined as:

```
export declare type MessageHandler = <EventType extends AnyEventName = AnyEventName>(type: AnyEventName, payload: EventPayload<EventType>) => void;
```

In the code there is also the following definition:

```
export declare type AnyEventPayload = EventPayload<AnyEventName>;
```

the message handler I am passing is defined as follows:

```
(message_type: AnyEventName, payload: AnyEventPayload) => {
  console.log(message_type, payload)
  if (message_type === 'idCheck.applicantStatus' && payload.reviewStatus === 'completed') 
    { 
      router.push('/')
    }
}
```

However I the IDE complains that `Property 'reviewStatus' does not exist on type 'AnyEventPayload'. Property 'reviewStatus' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)`

When I hover over `AnyEventPayload` I get:

```
(alias) type AnyEventPayload = {} | {
    idDocSetType: string;
    types: string[];
    videoRequired?: string | undefined;
} | {
    idDocSetType: string;
} | {
    applicantId: string;
} | {
    reprocessing: boolean;
    levelName: string;
    creationDate: string;
    expireDate: string;
    reviewStatus: string;
    autoChecked: boolean;
} | {
    ...;
} | {
    ...;
} | {
    ...;
} | SnsError
import AnyEventPayload
```

`reviewStatus` is there so I don't understand why it's complaining or How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AnyEventPayload` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type (which means that it might be any of those type variations between the union operators (`|`). Because of this, the `reviewStatus` property name might not be a part of the type, so in order to safely check that the `payload` value is of the type that includes that property, you can use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) the type to that specific variation. To do so, you just need to precede the equality check which accesses the property with an expression using the `in` operator so that TS can be sure that the property exists before trying to access it and compare its value:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=23&ssc=3&pln=28&pc=22#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAogNwnYAFAhiANgeywBMoBeKAbwF8oAfSgKCigEsiARfAYwGUJgAKuAgAuKAGdgAJxZwA5gG4mUUJHFjJM+QG0AukubI2EfACUIARwCuLKRCIB+DdNly6UK3CIQAZrPtKNPQUymycvPxCkM5aigxBjMxYYGC4LFxY6ACSRDGuge4hzHZgUtwQ4uKuYgBG+Pi4EJkGUI2ouAByWAC2ohIu8i1cdljALPhw7KN9mvnKEAAeYLYQU8AzA3HFEEYQAO48wKNW6v2xLVhWwPgAwgAWEFwA1va19Y3N8QpQAPQ-UPwuAA6BgMVTQeBIVDoLq9MhnObeLi4LB2KBcCaSKBlK4QKRiChQMAnO5QAAUsmJwDy8gAlGJkPg2FAqEoGBi4Fi7pkiI0pPCyb1Klg5BAAPrgsSQlBoYCwiAAGiJOAIxClCBl6GweEIRFpZAAfIl0ZiGhAgQQ5IKKuIReLwUqwCrdbTQj5ycpmELbaKJcIyKRyAByNj3R5PIHJVLpTLAQ7HcRBz2-f4wIgkYAPKA+BoEPaudEPZ4qfAAzlWNGZ0YqLOlfCQKSgAELFiScSsOA16D4GoAK0ewGTADIh1Ag3ZdgcjsATkGO8qdcRh6OnYuiECJyx9vGZ+3A8GMd1Uvx7EnmPqcespEDieI7mSgz8g7TAgogA)

```ts
if (
  message_type === 'idCheck.applicantStatus'
  // Add the following check to ensure that the property exists in the object
  && 'reviewStatus' in payload
  && payload.reviewStatus === 'completed'
) router.push('/');
```